# Cassandra Failed to format value OrderedMapSerializedKey

Tags: cassandra

I'm reading the article: http://christopher-batey.blogspot.com.br/2015/05/cassandra-aggregates-min-max-avg-group.html

And I have the following function and aggregate

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION group_data( state Map<text, int>, type text )
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
RETURNS Map<text, int>
LANGUAGE java AS '
Integer count = (Integer) state.get(type);  if (count == null) count = 1; else count++; state.put(type, count); return state; ' ;

CREATE OR REPLACE AGGREGATE group_and_count(text) 
SFUNC group_data 
STYPE Map<text, int> 
INITCOND {};
```

But when I run the command: **cqlsh:> select group_and_count(name) from test;** I get the following error: **Failed to format value OrderedMapSerializedKey([(u'gleydson', 4)]) : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sub_types'**

Comment: I found the answer, this is a cqlsh bug. https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index/issues/210